# Selenium how to click Ctrl + p

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver

I need to open the print window. I have used below code but it's not working.

`Keys. Chord(Keys.CONTROL,"p")`

I have used another way to click on a random element and used below code.

```
Driver. findElement(By.id("something")).sendKeys(Keys.Control +"p")
```

Both are not working.  Request to provide the suggestion for this.

Comment: Hi please include selenium tag. You are missing lots of people.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please specify your web browser?

Any way .sendKeys and Actions are not work.

But you can get print message in any browser using **JavaScriptExecutor**:

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.print()");
```